# "HP Insight Management WBEM Providers" download

Tags: powershell, hp, hp-proliant, wmi

I am trying to query a Proliant Server's health thru Powershell. But I can't find a place to  download the `HP Insight Management WBEM Providers` from [here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/home/?sp4ts.oid=3659620&ac.admitted=1383362916433.876444892.199480143).

Is there any other Powershell equivalent of the `HPacucli`.

Comment: What model server are you trying to monitor?

Comment: @ewwhite `PROLIANT BL460 G7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem downloading the software from HP's website.

http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-windows/p2068416648/v87200/cp020347.exe

Comment: Is this the same for all models of Proliant servers.

Comment: @AyanMullick Yes.

Comment: @ewwhite Could you please also share the documentation for this ie. how to query the health of the server.

Answer (score 0):

All HP software and drive downloads for your server, the [HP ProLiant BL460c G7 blade server](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c02535780-7%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1393245823296.876444892.492883150), are available at the following link: [**ProLiant BL460 G7 downloads**](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?cc=us&cc=us&lang=en&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=4194638&ac.admitted=1393245692344.876444892.492883150)

Choose your operating system, then pick the components you need. In general, you want most of the items listed [here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=4194638&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D4064%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#Software%20-%20System%20Management).